# What properties are supported by arguments object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was asked this question in an interview on NodeJS,

What are the properties supported by arguments object.

```
a) caller
b) callee
c) length
d) All
```

When I googled then I found that all the [3 properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) are present for an argument object.

But if I try to test this with a sample program I see that only Length property is present.

Here is my sample program:

```
var events = 'HelloWorld'

abc(events);
function abc(args) {
    console.log(args.charAt(1))   
    console.log(args.callee);
    console.log(args.caller);
    console.log(args.length);
}
```

Here is the output:

```
e
undefined
undefined
10
```

So based on above output only length is the valid property, but based on above all 3 are valid properties. So what is the correct answer for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your scoped variable `args` and the local variable `Function.arguments` are two very different things. In your function `abc(args)`, `args` is the scoped variable that will be whatever you pass into its invocation.

`arguments`, however, is a local array-like variable that is accessible inside each function call, and corresponds with the values passed into a function. For example:

```
function foo(args) {
    console.log(args);
    console.log(arguments[0]);
    console.log(arguments[1]);
    console.log(arguments[2]);
}

foo("bar", "baz", 123, 456);
```

This will output:

```
> "bar"
> "bar"
> "baz"
> 123
```

Even though this function only takes one argument, `args`, the local variable `arguments` is still present, and it represents *all* arguments passed into this function. That way we can still find the value of the second, third, and fourth arguments even though they weren't declared as part of the function's scope.

The issue you're seeing is that you are trying to access properties of `Function.arguments` in your scoped variable `args`, when the two are simply different variables altogether. If you want to access those properties, reference `arguments` instead:

```
var events = 'HelloWorld'
abc(events);

function abc(args) { 
    console.log(args.charAt(1));   
    console.log(arguments.callee);
    // console.log(arguments.caller); //DEPRECATED
    console.log(arguments.length);
}
```

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that `arguments.caller` is depreciated to the point of being obsolete. I don't think it works in recent versions of node.